# Container with 3 div's, using Flex-box/Grid

Tags: html, css, flexbox, grid, css-grid

Basicly what I want is 3 divs.
One rectangle above
and 2 small squares lined next to each other, below that.

Who can help me with this?
In below code, I can create 3 squares. But there's 2 at the top, 1 at the bottom.

But I want one rectangle that's above the lower 2 smaller squares. If that makes sense.

[------------------]

[---]   ]---]

```
 <section class="story story--spaceous">
  <div class="hero__compact-inner">
          <div class="grid">
            <div class="grid__row">
              <div class="grid__col">
                <h2 class="hero__subtitle">
                  Laag 6: Endpoint Security
                </h2>
                <p class="story__intro">
                  Antivirussystemen zorgen voor de optimale veiligheid binnen jouw organisatie. Het regelmatig updaten hiervan verkleint de risico's en kalamiteiten.
                  </p>
                  <div class="flex-container-3-status">
                    <div class="status-dashboard">Status dashboard rechthoek</div>
                    <div class="chart--donut">Donut Diagram Algemene Score</div>
                    <div class="action-list box-50">Actielijst</div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
.flex-container-3-status{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;

}

.flex-container-3-status> div{
  flex: 0 40%;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  margin-top: 45px;
  border: #fff solid;
  box-sizing: border-box
}
```

Comment: You have provided code for something other than the issue you need to solve. Please provide the code you are actually having problems with.

Comment: Editted, cause I accidently pasted the wrong CSS. Updated the question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 4 `div`s in the flex container. Define the `flex-basis` property for the first `div` as:

```
.flex-container-4 > div:first-child {
  flex-basis: 100%;
}
```

This will make the first `div` span 100% of the width and the rest of the `div`s will align themselves in the next row.

You may also need to adjust the `flex: 0 40%;` declaration for your `.flex-container-4 > div`, accordingly. `flex: 0 50%;`, if you have 2 more `div`s remaining, or `flex: 0 33.33%;`, if there are 3 `div`s remaining (as your code suggests).

Comment: Cheers! The flex basis and first child definetly works. Even in a 3 div container. Thanks :D

Comment: I would appreciate if you mark any of the answers here, (if) that solved your problem, as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I just add two classes `box-full` and `box-50` for set the different styles to each like below...

```
.box-full{
  flex: 1 100%;

}
.box-50{
  flex:1 50%;
}
```

```css
.flex-container-4 {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;

}

.flex-container-4 > div {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  margin-top: 45px;
  border: #fff solid;
  box-sizing: border-box
}
.box-full{
  flex: 1 100%;
  background:red;
}
.box-50{
  flex:1 50%;
  background:yellow;
}
```

```html
<section class="story story--spaceous">
        <div class="hero__compact-inner">
                <div class="grid">
                  <div class="grid__row">
                    <div class="grid__col">
                      <h2 class="hero__subtitle">
                        Laag 1: Bewustzijn
                      </h2>
                      <p class="story__intro">
                            Ruim de helft van security-calamiteiten wordt veroorzaakt door gebruikers. En slechts 41% van gebruikers kent het beleid ten aanzien van digitale veiligheid. Alleen al door bewustzijn van medewerkers te vergroten, weet je binnen jouw organisatie risico's sterk te beperken.
                        </p>
                        <div class="flex-container-4">
                          <div class="chart--donut box-full">Donut Diagram Algemene Score</div>
                          <div class="chart--donut box-50">Circel Diagram Recente Maatregelen</div>
                          <div class="chart--radar box-50">Radar Chart Verantwoordelijkheid</div>
                          <div class="action-list">To do list ul</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

is this what you want?

Comment: Yes! I see that I wrote down the wrong html section. It's supposed to be this (3 divs), i editted the question now. I am going to try and use this box full and 50%!

Comment: I updated the first post now. Your method worked on an other div container, that was pasted wrongly from my side. Do you think you can manage it with 3 divs with the updated code above?

Comment: I think CSS remains the same for three boxes too. you just need to add class to full div and half div.